# How should I calculate the time that the player has spent away from the app?

Tags: java, android, date

In the game I'm making in Android Studio, I want to have an object that erodes over time. Once the object is fully eroded, the player can bust it for points. I want this time value to be based on real world time so that the item continues to erode while the app is closed.

What would be the best way to accomplish this? Should I use Date variables, or can I get away with something simpler?

Comment: use a **timer task** with alarm manger if required

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty easy approach you can use via `sharedprefrences` and `service`, when app got killed save the time date variable and when user came back to your app, you can check the value against your saved key, if it is not null compare it with your current time and get the difference between both. That is how you can get that.

Answer (score 0):

When the object starts eroding, save the time : 
`long startTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();`

In your `onPause()`, save this time:

```
public void onPause() {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putLong("startTime", startTime );
    editor.commit();
    super.onPause();
}
```

In your `onResume()`, get the saved time and compare with current time:

```
public void onResume() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    long startTime =  prefs.getLong("startTime", 0);
    long elapsedTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - startTime;

    if (elapsedTime > EROTION_TIME) {
        // Voila !! The object has eroded.
    }
}
```

Comment: i guess it's a real good choice considering the documentation (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html) as mentioned: SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()  return the time since the system was booted [...] This clock is guaranteed to be monotonic [...] so is the recommend basis for general purpose interval timing.

Comment: it's really not. When the devices reboots that clock is reset. You should just use the 'regular' millis since epoch